# can i use a 700c tire (Gatorskin 700c x23) on a 650 wheel

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility, wheels

I am thinking of getting some Velocity Rims that are 650c but I am wondering if I will be able to use my 700x23c Gatorskin tires on them? Also what do you think about 650c wheels pros and cons.

Also, lets say I just buy the 650 rims do I need to change anything else in the bike? I have a Fuji Newest 3.0, I think the 2008 version, if that helps.

Comment: also,lets say i just buy the 650 tires do i need to change anything else in the bike? I have Fuji Newest 3.0 i think 2008 version. if that helps.

Comment: If you have rim brakes you'd need to change those out.  Pedal clearance will be less.  Not a good idea, generally.

Comment: Indeed. Most people also go 700c->650b if they do this conversion as well. Why are you doing this conversion anyway?

Answer (score 12):

No you will not be able to use your 700x23c tire on a 650c rim. The bead seat diameter of 700c rims is 622mm, this will also be the bead diameter of the your 700x23c tire.  The bead seat diameter of a 650c rim is 571mm (see [Velocity's Spec section](http://store.velocityusa.com/p/road-wheelset-650c)). Your 700x23c tire will be 51mm too wide.

Comment: If you do go the 650c route you will also need long calliper brakes.  Standard road callipers have a reach of 39-49 mm. The rim will move 51mm/2 = 25.5 mm towards the hub. A brake calliper with a reach of 65-75 mm will be required. These exist, for example Tektro R559(Long Arms) are 53-73 mm.

Answer (score 5):

As an owner of both 650c and 700c-wheeled bikes will happily share my thoughts.

First of all, 650c wheels are lighter and obviously smaller which makes the whole ride more dynamic which can improve your maneuverability.
On the other hand, 650c wheels are prone to sliding on stones or corners so you must be more careful when riding. 650c wheels spin faster so be ready to change tires sooner than on 700c bike.

Most makers make good tires for both 650 and 700 wheels, but 700 are more popular and therefore you end up with better choice. When it comes to wheels the picture is even grimmer... However, it just takes little more searching - many makers produce 650c versions of their wheels too.

The size difference between 700 and 650c wheels is very significant so there's no way to fit 700c tires onto 650c wheels.

Changing wheels from 700c to 650c is in usually bad idea, because you will have to move brakes (usually impossible) and most likely the bottom part of your bracket will be too low and pedals too close to the ground to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to look is Sheldon Brown's famous site. http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

I would suggest given the difference in diamaeter you will run into issues attempting to put your 700x23c tyres on a 650c rim.

Answer (score 0):

For the question in the comment:

You will have to move the brake pad a bit further down to adapt to the smaller rim. This may possibly lead to that you have to change the brake. Check how much you can lower the brake pad.

Comment: The brakes will have to be able to accommodate a 51mm/2 = 25.5 mm drop of the braking surface towards the hub. Most standard road callipers have a reach of 39-49 mm.  A brake caliper with a reach of 65-75 mm will be required.  These exist, for example Tektro R559(Long Arms) are 53-73 mm.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, no.
The rims are different sizes, 700 vs 650, so obviously each will take a different size tire.
Why do you want to change to a smaller wheel?
Brakes likely will not reach rim. 
Bicycle would be closer to ground.